# incompatible with option -fdefault-real-8 during compilation

Tags: variables, fortran, implicit

Im trying to install campari  (is a program to molecular simulations) version 3 in a Centos System, the program can be download in this link:

http://campari.sourceforge.net

I had installed the libraries hd5f, ftw, zlib, etc, following this tutorial https://gist.github.com/alexholehouse/57feab526750fb1ec942

but when I try compiler (make campari), I have this error message. Sincerily, I don't know fortran and I was searching something about it and I dont have idea how resolve it.

Any could help me or guide me about this point?

Thanks so much

```
Warning: Use of the NUMERIC_STORAGE_SIZE named constant from intrinsic module ISO_FORTRAN_ENV at (1) is incompatible with option -fdefault-real-8 /data2/teresa/campari_abs/source/graph_algorithms.f90:1052.39:

      kr = (1.0*iters)/(max(1_INT64 (tts(2)-tts(1)))/thrdat%rate) ! iterati
                                       1
Error: Missing kind-parameter at (1)
/data2/teresa/campari_abs/source/graph_algorithms.f90:3456.34:

  use, INTRINSIC:: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
                                  1 
Warning: Use of the NUMERIC_STORAGE_SIZE named constant from intrinsic module ISO_FORTRAN_ENV at (1) is incompatible with option -fdefault-real-8 /data2/teresa/campari_abs/source/graph_algorithms.f90:3593.42:

        kr = (1.0*iterations)/(max(1_INT64,(tts(2)-tts(1)))/thrdat%rate) !iter
                                          1
Error: Syntax error in COMPLEX constant at (1)
make: *** [/data2/teresa/campari_abs/lib/x86_64/graph_algorithms.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Please always copy error messages as text. Just do copy and paste. It is *very* important, because the error message must be searchable. [edit] your question with the text output. See [ask] for more.

Comment: Also see [mcve]. You must include everything necessary to reproduce the error. If it is a common software, it can be a link to the distribution, but you MUST tell us the **exact** steps you did. Describe all steps you did. All the commands end flags you used. Do not skip anything. Copy all the commands here as text. You must also specify the *exact* version of the code and where we can get it.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm going to do it right now.